# On the proof of Asymptotic Normality of GLM-Estimator: understanding some $o_p(1)$ statements

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, maximum-likelihood

Also the framework is kind of annoying, my questions at the end of the text should be rather standard:

---

**Framework**

I am trying to understand the proof for the asymptotical normality of the maximum likelihood estimator in a GLM-setting, which is given in the Book *From Finite Sample to Asymptotic Methods in Statistics* by de Lima, Singer and Sen in chapter 10.5 and have some problems following their arguments.

For the exponential family of distributions they derived 
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \beta \partial \beta'} \log L_n(\beta) & = \sum_{i=1}^N \{g'(\mu_i(\beta))\}^{-2}[v_i(\beta)]^{-1} x_ix_i'\\
&\quad + \sum_{i=1}^N(Y_i-\mu_i(\beta))\{\frac{g''(\mu_i(\beta)}{[g'(\mu_i(\beta)]^2}+\frac{b'''(h(x_i'\beta))}{[g'(\mu_i(\beta)]^2[v_i(\beta)]^3}\}x_ix_i' \\
= I_n(\beta)+r_n(\beta)
\end{align*}
where $\log L_n(\beta)$ is the log-Likelihood and $$I_n(\beta) =\sum_{i=1}^N \{g'(\mu_i(\beta)\}^{-2}[v_i(\beta)]^{-1} x_ix_i'=\mathbb{E}(-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \beta \partial \beta'} \log L_n(\beta) ) $$
is the Information matrix.

They then note that $r_n(\beta)$ is a sum of independent centered random variables with finite variances $v_i(\mu_i(\beta))$ and nonstochastic matrix coefficients $G_i := \{\frac{g''(\mu_i(\beta)}{[g'(\mu_i(\beta)]^2}+\frac{b'''(h(x_i'\beta))}{[g'(\mu_i(\beta)]^2[v_i(\beta)]^3}\}x_ix_i'$

Among other things they assume (I already corrected some obvious mistakes):

1. (10.5.31) $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n v_i(\mu_i(\beta))trace(G_iG_i')=0$$

Define  $B(\delta)= \{\beta^*\in \mathbb{R}^q : ||\beta^*-\beta||<\delta\}$, $w_{1i}:= \{g'(\mu_i(\beta)\}^{-2}[v_i(\beta)]^{-1}$ and
$w_{2i}:=\mu_i(\beta)\{\frac{g''(\mu_i(\beta)}{[g'(\mu_i(\beta)]^2}+\frac{b'''(h(x_i'\beta))}{[g'(\mu_i(\beta)]^2[v_i(\beta)]^3}\}$
we then assume that we have as $\delta\to 0$:

2. (10.5.33)
   $$\sup_{\beta^*\in B(\delta)}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N || [w_{ki}(\beta^*)-w_{ki}(\beta)] x_ix_i'|| \to 0, \quad k=1,2$$
3. (10.5.34)
   $$\mathbb{E}\{\sup_{\beta^*\in B(\delta)}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n|Y_i|||[w_{2i}(\beta^*)-w_{2i}(\beta)] x_ix_i'||\} \to 0$$

---

**Questions:**

1. They say that it follows from (10.5.31) and the Chebyshev inequality, that $$n^{-1}r_n(\beta) = o_p(1)$$
   How can I see this?!
2. In their proof, at (10.5.38), they claim that it follows from (10.5.33) and (10.5.34) that $$\sup_{\beta^* \in B(K/\sqrt{n})} || \frac{1}{n} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \beta \partial \beta'} \log L_n(\beta)|_{\beta^*} - \frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \beta \partial \beta'} \log L_n(\beta)|_{\beta}||=o_p(1)$$
   I am not able to see this neither.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I repeat/generalize/simplify your first question to make it easier for others to respond:

- You have $n$ centered and independent  random variables $y_i$ with $var(y_i)=v_i(\mu_i(\beta))$ and a deterministic $q\times q$-matrix $G_i$
- You assume that $\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) trace(G_iG_i')\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

You want to show that with the random matrix $y_i^* = y_i G_i$ you have  $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^* = o_p(1).$$

---

Unfortunately I am not really familiar with the techniques used to proof such statements in the random-matrix-case.

But your assumption (the trace term) let one think about using the Frobenius-norm.

**Edit:** actual, the proof of the first statement is a lot easier than expected: note that we have $E(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^*) = 0$. Chose some arbitrary $1\leq k\leq q$ and $1\leq  l\leq q$ and look at the $kl$-th variable of the matrix $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^*$, i.e. look at $$z_{kl,n}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i {G_i}_{,kl}$$
We then have $E(z_{kl,n})=0$ and $$var(z_{kl,n}) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) {G_i}_{,kl}^2$$

But obviously we have $$v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) {G_i}_{,kl}^2\leq v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) ||G_i||_F^2 = v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) trace(G_iG_i')$$ and hence
 $$var(z_{kl,n}) \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) trace(G_iG_i').$$
Now, choose any $\varepsilon>0$ by the Markov inequality we have:
$$P(|z_{kl,n}|>\varepsilon) = P(|z_{kl,n}|^2>\varepsilon^2) \leq \frac{var(z_{kl,n})}{\varepsilon^2}\leq \frac{\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(\mu_i(\beta)) trace(G_iG_i')}{\varepsilon^2}\to 0$$

The assertion now follows since $k,l$ and $\varepsilon>0$ were arbitrary.

This should answere your first question.